# Is WCF MessageBuffer.CreateMessage thread safe?

Tags: wcf, thread-safety, reentrancy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messagebuffer(v=vs.85).aspx is somewhat vague when it says that *"Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."*

As a general rule, it seems like instance members do not have the thread-safe guarantee.

However, I'm guessing that some instance member methods are reentrant and thread-safe and others are not.

MessageBuffer.CreateMessage is an instance method. 
Has anyone confirmed whether this specific method is reentrant (or whether callers need to implement locking around calls to the method) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think until explicity specified, instance methods are always non thread safe. You can look at this method through reflector to confirm.
Also why are you concern about thread safety of this method? What is your usage scenario?

Comment: Our service maintains multiple MessageBuffers. These buffers are used to create messages frequently. 
I want to avoid the overhead of synchronization constructs for every CreateMessage call (unless, of course, the CreateMessage call is not reentrant)

Comment: What would you gain adding synchronization construct around create message. CreateMessage does not change state of the original object, so how does it make a difference if create message is called once or multiple time.

Comment: If the method is not reentrant (as you think it is), synchronization constructs will need to be added to make sure that the method isn't simultaneously executed by two different threads

Answer (score 1):

MessageBuffer.CreateMessage is abstract, so it doesn't make sense to ask whether it's thread safe or not. The subclasses of MessageBuffer in WCF are all internal, so they can potentially be changed. As Chandermani said, you should assume that it is not thread-safe.

Update: it is not thread-safe. The created message may have dependencies on other components, such as serialization of the message body. If those components aren't thread-safe, then the `CreateMessage` call cannot be considered thread-safe either.

In the example below, the serialized version of the object is time-dependent (it could have some additional dependencies as well), so the order in which the `CreateMessage` calls are made impacts the result.

```
public class StackOverflow_6209650_751090
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyDC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime SerializedTime
        {
            get { return DateTime.Now; }
            set { }
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        Message message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "foo", new MyDC());
        var buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.CreateMessage());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.CreateMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The CreateBuffer method doesn't concern me.
I was refering to the MessageBuffer object created by Message.CreateBufferedCopy (and specifically if the CreateMessage method of this object is reentrant or not).

Comment: Message.CreateBufferedCopy internally calls a virtual method OnCreateBufferedCopy, which depends on the type of message which is created. Also, I'll edit my answer with an example showing that it is definitely **not** thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the example Carlos, I've upvoted your comment. However, the DateTime.Now method (used in your example) is thread-safe.
As you mention, the returned-value is time-dependent. However, that doesn't mean that DateTime.Now is not thread-safe or not reentrant. On the contrary, DateTime.Now is a thread-safe method.


In any case, the specific message I'm creating is not time-based. I'm caching the MessageBuffer because the data (static xml) will not change during the period when it is cached. My guess is that CreateMessage is reentrant, but need to verify this.